# C - List is saving data recursively in all nodes

Tags: c, list

I'm trying to save a struct for each node I create within my list. The problem is, the program is propagating the data of the next iteration throughout all nodes in the list:

```
void listAdd(struct List *list, void *data) {
  if (list->head->data == NULL) {
    puts("!");
    list->head->data = data;
  } else {
    struct node *temp_node;
    temp_node = list->head;

    while (temp_node->next != NULL)
      temp_node = temp_node->next;
    temp_node->next = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp_node->next->next = NULL;
    temp_node->next->data = data;
  }
  if (list->head->data == data)
    puts("true");
  struct deltaobj *dobj = (struct deltaobj *)list->head->data;
  printf("%s,%s,%s\n", dobj->Istate, dobj->symbol, dobj->Fstate);
}
```

The print on the bottom clearly shows that I want to print only the values on the head of the list but the output is the following:

```
!
true
0,a,0
0,a,1
0,b,0
1,b,2
1,b,2
1,b,2
1,b,2
1,b,2
4
```

The 4 at the end is to count the number of elements in the list, to make sure I'm not making any mistakes there.

Here's the full code so you can verify:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct step
{
    char * symbol;
    char * state;
    char branch;
};

struct deltaobj
{
    char * Istate;
    char * symbol;
    char * Fstate;
};

struct node
{
    struct node * next;
    void * data;
};

struct List
{
    struct node * head;
};

struct Stack
{
    struct node * top;
};

struct Automata
{
    char ** Qstates;
    char ** Sigma;
    char *  Qinit;
    char ** Qend;
    struct List * deltatf;
    struct List * tops;
};

void listInit(struct List * list, void * data)
{
    list->head = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    list->head->data = data;
    list->head->next = NULL;
}

void listAdd(struct List * list, void * data)
{
    if(list->head->data == NULL)
    {
        puts("!");
        list->head->data = data;
    }
    else
    {

        struct node * temp_node;
        temp_node = list->head;

        while(temp_node->next != NULL) temp_node = temp_node->next;
        temp_node->next = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        temp_node->next->next = NULL;
        temp_node->next->data = data;
    }
    if(list->head->data==data)puts("true");
    struct deltaobj * dobj = (struct deltaobj *)list->head->data;
    printf("%s,%s,%s\n",dobj->Istate,dobj->symbol,dobj->Fstate);
}

void stackInit(struct Stack * stack,void * data)
{
    stack->top = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    stack->top->data = data;
    stack->top->next = NULL;
}

void dataAssign(struct node * _node, void * data) {    _node->data = data; }

void * getNodeData(struct node * node) { return node->data; }

void automataInit(struct Automata * avto, char * filename)
{

    FILE * file = fopen(filename,"r");
    const char delim[3] = ",\n";
    char line[50];
    char * token;

    avto->deltatf = malloc(sizeof(struct List *));
    avto->tops = malloc(sizeof(struct List *));
    listInit(avto->deltatf,NULL);
    listInit(avto->tops,NULL);

    for(int i =0;i<4;i++)
    {
        if(fgets(line,150,file)!=NULL)
        {
            char * ptr = line;
            int elements = 0;

            while((ptr = strpbrk(ptr,"\n,")) != NULL)
            {
                elements++;
                ptr++;
            }

            switch(i)
            {
                case 0: avto->Qstates = malloc(sizeof(char*)*elements);
                    break;
                case 1: avto->Sigma = malloc(sizeof(char*)*elements); 
                    break;
                case 2: line[strlen(line)-1] = '\0'; avto->Qinit = line; 
                    break;
                case 3: avto->Qend = malloc(sizeof(char*)*elements); 
                    break;
            }
            if (i==2) continue;

            char ** pttr;
            token = strtok(line,delim);
            pttr = avto->Qstates;

            while( token != NULL )
            {
                *pttr = token;
                pttr++;
                token = strtok(NULL,delim);
            }
        }
    }

    while(fgets(line,150,file) != NULL)
    {
        int count = 0;
        struct deltaobj * rule = malloc(sizeof(struct deltaobj));
        token = strtok(line,delim);
        while( token != NULL )
        {
            strcat(token,"\0");
            if(count==0) { rule->Istate = token; }
            if(count==1) { rule->symbol = token; }
            if(count==2) { rule->Fstate = token; }

            count++;
            token = strtok(NULL,delim);
        }

        listAdd(avto->deltatf,(void *)rule);
    }
    fclose(file);
}


void listCount(struct List * list)
{
    struct node * temp = list->head;
    int count = 0;
    while(temp != NULL)
        {
            struct deltaobj *dobj = (struct deltaobj *)temp->data;
            printf("%s,%s,%s\n",dobj->Istate,dobj->symbol,dobj->Fstate);
            temp = temp->next;
            count++;
        }
    printf("%d\n",count);
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    struct Automata * avto = malloc(sizeof(struct Automata));
    automataInit(avto,"text.txt");
    struct deltaobj * dobj = (struct deltaobj *)getNodeData(avto->deltatf->head);
    char * shito = dobj->symbol;
    listCount(avto->deltatf);
    printf("%s,%s,%s\n",dobj->Istate,dobj->symbol,dobj->Fstate);

}
```

Comment: Your code don't produce the output you post, please post a [mcve] !

Comment: Can it be a pastebin? The complete code is too big.

Comment: I will advice you to reduce it, I'm pretty sure you will find the bug yourself if you create your [mcve].

Comment: "The complete code is too big." Then you should actually click on the link that two others have shared and read the suggestions.

Comment: You should also learn how to debug your own code. Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for some tips.

Comment: How does `char line[50];` and `if(fgets(line,150,file)!=NULL)` make sense? What happens if line is between `50-150` chars? `#define` constants to prevent this type of mismatch.

Comment: Show the contents (or at least the first 20 lines or so) of `text.txt`. Otherwise, your code compiles fine, aside from the unused `shito`, `argc` and `argv`...

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin sure: https://pastebin.com/zt6C9Hns

Comment: It must be related with the way I'm passing those structures to the list because it does work normally with primitives like int or char (I tested with a simple for, passing values).

Comment: How do you know that it went wrong? You haven't posted anything to show that `the program is propagating the data of the next iteration throughout all nodes in the list`

Comment: @4386427 the modification made to the function listCount() outputs the very last line: 1,b,2.

Comment: @KoltPenny That is exactly the last line of the file - isn't it? What did you expect?

Comment: @4386427 it prints the same line 4 times when it should print 4 distinct lines.

Comment: @KoltPenny You really need to edit your question so the output is correct. Currently the said output has 4 different lines! If you really have 4 identical lines, you should post that info. We can't help if you don't give us correct info.

Comment: I just edited the part of the output where it shows that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than being incredibly hard to read because you don't put much space in your code (especially for older eyes...), you are having problems with how you allocate memory, e.g.

```
void automataInit(struct Automata * avto, char * filename)
...
//     avto->deltatf = malloc(sizeof(struct List *));
//     avto->tops = malloc(sizeof(struct List *));
    avto->deltatf = malloc (sizeof *avto->deltatf);
    avto->tops = malloc (sizeof *avto->tops);
```

You originally allocate for `sizeof(struct List *)` that is the `sizeof (a pointer)`. Which is insufficient. If you always allocate based on the dereferenced pointer, as shown above, you type sizing will always be correct. The same applies for:

```
        switch(i) {
            // case 0: avto->Qstates = malloc(sizeof(char*)*elements);
            case 0: avto->Qstates = malloc (sizeof *avto->Qstates * elements);
                break;
            // case 1: avto->Sigma = malloc(sizeof(char*)*elements); 
            case 1: avto->Sigma = malloc (sizeof *avto->Sigma * elements); 
                break;
            case 2: line[strlen(line)-1] = '\0';
                avto->Qinit = line; 
                break;
            // case 3: avto->Qend = malloc(sizeof(char*)*elements); 
            case 3: avto->Qend = malloc (sizeof *avto->Qend * elements); 
                break;
        }
```

Next, your statement `strcat (token,"\0");` makes no sense at all. If `token` wasn't already nul-terminated, you would have just invoked *Undefined Behavior* by passing it as an argument to a function expecting a string.

You don't use `argc` or `argv`, so your declaration for `main` is `int main (void)`. You don't use `shito` (yet), so it is another variable that can be removed.

Putting it altogether, and setting `list->head->next = NULL;` in `listInit` as @StephenDocy suggested, I get your desired output with the following changes,

```
#define HDRL  4     /* if you need constants, define them   */
#define MAXL 50     /* don't use magic numbers in your code */
...
void automataInit(struct Automata * avto, char * filename)
{
    FILE *file = fopen (filename,"r");
    const char *delim = ",\n";
    char line[MAXL];
    char *token;

    if (file == NULL) {      /* validation file open succeeded */
        perror ("fopen-filename");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
//     avto->deltatf = malloc(sizeof(struct List *));
//     avto->tops = malloc(sizeof(struct List *));
    avto->deltatf = malloc (sizeof *avto->deltatf);
    avto->tops = malloc (sizeof *avto->tops);
    listInit (avto->deltatf, NULL);
    listInit (avto->tops, NULL);

    for(int i = 0; i < HDRL; i++) {
        if (fgets (line, MAXL, file) != NULL) {
            char *ptr = line;
            int elements = 0;

            while ((ptr = strpbrk (ptr,"\n,")) != NULL) {
                elements++;
                ptr++;
            }

            switch(i) {
                // case 0: avto->Qstates = malloc(sizeof(char*)*elements);
                case 0: avto->Qstates = malloc (sizeof *avto->Qstates * elements);
                    break;
                // case 1: avto->Sigma = malloc(sizeof(char*)*elements); 
                case 1: avto->Sigma = malloc (sizeof *avto->Sigma * elements); 
                    break;
                case 2: line[strlen(line)-1] = '\0';
                    avto->Qinit = line; 
                    break;
                // case 3: avto->Qend = malloc(sizeof(char*)*elements); 
                case 3: avto->Qend = malloc (sizeof *avto->Qend * elements); 
                    break;
            }
            if (i==2) continue;

            // char **pttr;
            char **pttr = avto->Qstates;
            token = strtok (line,delim);
            // pttr = avto->Qstates;

            int n = 0;
            while( n < elements && token != NULL ) {
                *pttr = token;
                pttr++;
                n++;
                token = strtok (NULL,delim);
            }
        }
    }

    while (fgets (line,MAXL,file) != NULL) {
        int count = 0;
        struct deltaobj *rule = malloc (sizeof (struct deltaobj));
        token = strtok (line,delim);

        while( token != NULL ) {  /* you must allocate for Istate, etc... */
            // strcat (token,"\0");  /* makes no sense */
            if (count==0) { rule->Istate = strdup(token); }
            if (count==1) { rule->symbol = strdup(token); }
            if (count==2) { rule->Fstate = strdup(token); }

            count++;
            token = strtok (NULL,delim);
        }

        listAdd (avto->deltatf, rule);
    }
    fclose(file);
}
```

(**note:** you must validate your `fopen` succeeded before attempting to read from the file stream and you must allocate for `Istate, symbol, Fstate` and caught by @4386427. Using `strdup` is as simple as anything else -- don't forget to `free` that memory when no longer needed)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/ll_gA908gs0
!
true
0,a,0
0,a,0
0,a,0
0,a,0
4
0,a,0
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Yes, thanks. If `strdup` isn't available, he can just use `rule->Istate = malloc (strlen (token) + 1); strcpy (rule-Istate, token);`

Comment: `list->head->next = NULL;` was already in listInit() and I was just about to use `argv` to input the name of the file but I had to test the function first, thanks. Your answer really opened my eyes. I learned C on my own and there are many things you simply don't learn from reading the books. I'll take your advice and pay more attention to those details.

Comment: Glad it helped. Enjoy learning C (you never actually learn it all -- it's more of a journey), but there is no better language to teach you how to program. Many languages try and hide the details from you. With C, you have the power, and responsibility, to manage memory, storage, bounds, etc.. Always keep a link to [C11 Standard (latest public draft)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html) handy, and listen to your compiler. If you (and you should) compile with warnings enabled -- you can learn a lot of C, just by understanding what your compiler is telling you. Good luck with your coding.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here

```
        if(count==0) { rule->Istate = token; }
        if(count==1) { rule->symbol = token; }
        if(count==2) { rule->Fstate = token; }
```

You save `token` which is a char* into somewhere in `line`. So all your `deltaobj` contains pointers into `line`. So whenever `line` is changed, all your `deltaobj` will seem to change as well. When `line` goes out of scope, they will point to illegal memory (i.e. undefined behavior). So that code must be changed.

You could do

```
struct deltaobj
{
    char Istate[150];
    char symbol[150];
    char Fstate[150];
};
```

and

```
        if(count==0) { strcpy(rule->Istate, token); }
        // change the other 2 lines as well
```

Then the output is:

```
!
true
0,a,0
0,a,0
0,a,0
0,a,0
0,a,0
0,a,1
0,b,0
1,b,2
4
0,a,0
```

or you can keep the struct as is and then assign dynamic memory.

In any case, you need a **string copy**. You can't just save pointers in `line`

Comment: I suspected it had to do with that part of the code. I even had problems before with the stdout because of that. Thanks, And I'll take in account all yours and others recommendations for future questions.